# How to allow different Sub-Range Types in a single Function Type

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I have a group of functions that use Sub-Range types for their input parameter.

```
const
  ImprovementNodeCount = 20;
  SaleAllocationNodeCount = 10;

type   
  TImprovementNodePrintOrders = 0..ImprovementNodeCount;
  TSaleAllocationNodePrintOrders = 0..SaleAllocationNodeCount;


  function SaleImprovementType(PrintOrder: TImprovementNodePrintOrders): TSaleReferenceRecord;

  function SaleAllocationType(PrintOrder: TSaleAllocationNodePrintOrders): TSaleReferenceRecord;
  function SaleAllocationAcres(PrintOrder: TSaleAllocationNodePrintOrders): TSaleReferenceRecord;
  // many more functions with different SubTypes
```

This has been working very well for me.  I have a new situation where it would be convenient to pass one of these functions as a parameter.  My sub-ranges are now causing problems because they are different types.

All of the functions look the same except for the sub-type.  I tried to add a new function type like this

```
  TGetReferenceFunction = function (Index: cardinal): TSaleReferenceRecord;
```

Right now the compiler complains that the types are different when I try to pass the function parameter as a TGetReferenceFunction. Is there any way to create a function type that will include all of these functions that have different sub-type parameters?

```
[DCC Error] SaleNameMap.pas(295): E2010 Incompatible types: 'Cardinal' and 'TImprovementNodePrintOrders'
```

What I really need is a type that is all numeric sub-types.  I know I can create a different function type for each sub-type I have, but that still will not let me pass these functions as parameters into one common function.

I'm guessing this is not possible.  If so I have some other options, but in case there is something I am missing I thought I would try here first.

Comment: Suppose that you have a single function, `F()`, that can receive both  `SaleImprovementType` and `SaleAllocationType`. Surely that means that you have abandoned type safety. Because `F` cannot call the function pointer it is passed in a type safe way. At which point you may as well abandon the sub-types, or cast the function pointer.

Comment: I know I am giving up some type safety.  I would be happy with casting the function pointer but I just get "Invalid Typecast" when I try that.

Comment: You want to cast? Like this: `TGetReferenceFunction(@SaleAllocationAcres)`

Comment: Ah - I was missing the @ before the function name.  A cast works great for me in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want one function to accept all those distinct function types, then you'll have to sacrifice type safety. You can do this with a cast:

```
TGetReferenceFunction(@SaleAllocationAcres)
```

Comment: That's not nearly as bad as using a var untyped parameter, though.  that would be the truly brittle and crazy way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simulate a kind of *anonymous method* system.

For example:

```
// existing typed proc
function SaleAllocationType(PrintOrder: TSaleAllocationNodePrintOrders): TSaleReferenceRecord;
function SaleAllocationAcres(PrintOrder: TSaleAllocationNodePrintOrders): TSaleReferenceRecord

Type
  // the prototype
  SaleAllocProto = function(PrintOrder: TSaleAllocationNodePrintOrders): TSaleReferenceRecord;

 // enumeration for all the existing typed procs
 TSelAllocRef = (saType,saAcres);

Const
  // array which references all your typed procs.
  SelAllocProvider = Array[TSelAllocRef] Of TSelAllocRef = (SaleAllocationType,SaleAllocationAcres);
```

Then you can call

```
ASaleReferenceRecord := SelAllocProvider[saType](Myargument);
AnotherSaleReferenceRecord := SelAllocProvider[saAcres](Myargument)
```

Comment: `.. Array[TSelAllocRef] Of SaleAllocProto ..`. In any case I'm not sure this would count as passing different type of functions to a single function.

Comment: Yes you're right I've totally switched the *// many more functions with different SubTypes*. Maybe if the argument in the prototype is replaced by an untyped parameter this would work: *SaleAllocProto = function(Var InputData): TSaleReferenceRecord;*

Comment: Untyped var param = open door to worlds of hurt. Avoid.